# How to draw a line in 3d space?

Tags: unity

I have a top down billiard game. And on click / tap the ball moves in the clicked direction like in the image below:

[image]

Now, I want a line to be drawn in the direction where the mouse is hovers or the finger is swiped, here is my update code:

```
void Update () {

        //this should make the line, why not working?
Vector3 forward = transform.forward; 
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward);
Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + forward * 10000);


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            //
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f)){

                //


                //
                Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
                Vector3 clickPos = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.z);
                Vector3 direction = Direction (clickPos - startPos);

                //direction
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(direction.x * 5, direction.y * 5, 0);


            }



        }



    }
```

I tried DrawLine, Drawray, any ideas?

Comment: What object is that update-function attached to? Is it possible you are actually drawing the line *below* the plane?

Comment: By the way, a more appropriate class than `Debug` for drawing spatial user interfaces is the class [`Gizmos`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html). Any calls to it need to be in the `OnDrawGizmoz` event.

Comment: The script is attached to the object WhiteBall, the white ball in the 8 ball pool game, is that ok?

Comment: Another problem could be that the default color for Debug.drawLine is white, just as your background. Could you be drawing white-on-white? Also, did you check if `transform.forward` relative to your cueball is maybe *downwards*?

Comment: are Gismos turned on ? are you looking in debug window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html). That's a component which draws a line in 3D space.

Answer (score 0):

Ask jhocking said you could use a LineRenderer and then apply a texture to it for the Ray to get the effect you want. LineRenderer could be easily controlled from a script.